# Compress and Encrypt (AES 256) excel files in (streams) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, encryption, compression

I need a package with encryption and compressions methods.

Preferably compress/decompress and encrpyt/desencrypt large streams correctly.

Comment: First compress with zip then encrypt with AES.

Comment: Compressing after encryption will yield no to minimal benefit, because properly-encrypted data is undistinguishable from random data, and compression relies on pattern identification and replacement to provide the size decrease. Please be aware that compression can cause security issues when joined with encryption. You should carefully evaluate if the impact to your threat model outweighs the benefits of compression. See [this explanation of the CRIME attack](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19914/16485) for more info.

Comment: It is not the compression but the way the SSL protocol was designed and handles cookies. Just compressing and encrypting is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# [Cryptography](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoCryptography/) package, C# [Compression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoIOCompression/) and NuGet `NequeoIOCompress` packages.

The Cryptography package includes cryptography classes for AES, RSA, 3DES, Blowfish, Twofish, CMS, PGP, EllipticCurve, Rijndael and some others. It also includes data protection classes using the .Net built in `ProtectedData` class. You can use this package as you wish.

The Compression packages includes compression classes for Bzip2, Zip, Huffman, Zlib, GZip and 7zip compression. You can use these packages as you wish.

Using AES in the Cryptography package, a quick sample.

```
// Create a new AES cryto.
using (AdvancedAES aes = new AdvancedAES())
{
    bool ret = false;

    ret = aes.EncryptFile(pathToDecryptedFile, pathToEncryptedFile, Key, IV);
    ret = aes.DecryptFile(pathToDecryptedFile, pathToEncryptedFile, Key, IV);
}
```

The code above is as simple as is gets to encrypt and decrypt a file, you can also encrypt and decrypt within a `Stream`, `String` and `byte[]`, it also has built-in `async` capabilities. Another feature is the ability (AES) to change the `BlockSize`, `CipherMode`, `KeySize`, and `PaddingMode` before encrypting or decrypting.

Cryptography classes such as Blowfish, Twofish and Rijndael have just quick encrypt and decrypt methods where you can just pass in `byte[]` data and `byte[]` encrypted or decrypted data is returned.

Cryptography classes such as PGP has more capabilities including signing and verifying input data, using public and secret keys.

Cryptography classes such as RSA is capable of encryption and decryption of files and streams using file based x509 certificates or if the certificate is located within the store.

Using GZip in the Compress package, a quick sample.

```
Nequeo.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Decompress(zipStream, unZipStream);
Nequeo.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Compress(unZipStream, zipStream);
```

It is that simple to compress and decompress GZip, ZLib data.

Using 7zip in the Compress package, a quick sample.

```
Nequeo.IO.Compression.SevenZip.Decompress(zipFilename, unZipDirectorPath);
Nequeo.IO.Compression.SevenZip.Compress(zipFilename, zipDirectorPath);
```

Use the same Compression package (NuGet `NequeoIOCompression`) to compress and decompress data with BZip2, Zip and 7Zip.

As stated above these three NuGet packages are free for you to use and distribute. Note that the 7Zip compression relies on the 7zip.dll for x64, x86 processing. If you install the compression packages the 7zip.dll binaries are included.

Comment: Copying and pasting links into a single sentence answer isn't considered helpful here.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, I'm not trying to insult you or undermine your contribution, I'm simply saying that your answer could be improved. Maybe include a code example in your answer? Reading the [help] might be useful too.

Comment: Nice edit and example code.